# Knowing the zero coefficients in partial fractions from the beginning

Tags: partial-fractions

While solving partial fractions and getting the coefficients, can we know from the beginning that some coefficients will be zero? How?

For example
$$\frac{1}{S^2(S^2+4)}=\frac{A}{S^2}+\frac{B}{S}+\frac{CS+D}{S^2+4}$$
If we compute the coefficients, we will get these values
$$A=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$B=C=0$$
$$D=\frac{-1}{4}$$
Can we know before solving that B and C will be zeros? How?

Another example
$$\frac{1}{(S^2+1)(S^2+4)}=\frac{AS+B}{S^2+1}+\frac{CS+D}{S^2+4}$$
$$B=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$A=C=0$$
$$D=\frac{-1}{3}$$
I am asking this question because while solving in a book, I found that the book assumed these coefficients to be zero from the beginning, i.e., it is written that
$$\frac{1}{S^2(S^2+4)}=\frac{A}{S^2}+\frac{D}{S^2+4}$$
$$\frac{1}{(S^2+1)(S^2+4)}=\frac{B}{S^2+1}+\frac{D}{S^2+4}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, before partial fraction decomposition, let $x=S^2$ and everything will become clear.

After the partial fraction decomposition, just replace $x$ by $S^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\dfrac1{S^2(S^2+4)}$ is an even function, $B$ and $C$ must be $0$. The same argument applies to $\dfrac1{(S^2+1)(S^2+4)}$.